# servlet accept null values from checkboxes

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

[image]here I have a jsp page which allow the user to apply his name, his age and his mastered programming language

```
<form action="./getPost" method="POST" >

     <label> name </label>      <input type="text" name="name" > <br><br>
     <label> age </label> &nbsp <input type="text" name="age" > <br><br>


    <label> programming langage </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fav" value="java"> java <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fav" value="php"> php <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fav" value="python"> python <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit post">

    </form>
```

this is how the servlet get the data

```
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String age = request.getParameter("age");
        String[] lang = request.getParameterValues("fav");

            InsertPost.add(new Post(name, age, lang));
```

when I fill in all the fields of the form and click on the button it inserts the data into the database.
then I tested to submit it without selecting any checkbox which caused an error (java.lang.NullPointerException).
the issue is that I want to leave this optional means not required if the user wants to pick or not.
so how can I make the servlet handles null values ​​from checkboxes

Comment: help us with full logs here...

Comment: you mean what does the server displyed ?

Comment: yes the error that you got on server?

Comment: I've added it, it's in french by the way..

Comment: I am assuming you just expect null value for fav not for name and age? Did you check if you have any null constraint on the fav field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to solve this issue:

**Option 1:** *(sending empty string instead of null)*
Assuming that your table has a not-null constraint on field `fav`.

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String age = request.getParameter("age");
List<String> lang = request.getParameterValues("fav");
if(lang==null) {
    lang = new String[] {""};
}
InsertPost.add(new Post(name, age, lang));
//not recommended as it will add 1-byte of empty string even if there is no fav language
```

**Note:**

> You should put the `InsertPost.add(...)` call in a **try-catch** block to
>   handle exception during inserting data to DB and then show it on UI as a part of best
>   practices. Also, put a check if the name and age are null and handle it.

**Option 2:** *(sending null and removing null constraint from the table on `fav` field)*

```
//how you are doing it previously will work.
InsertPost.add(new Post(name, age, lang));
```

**Cause of error**

---

Your database is not expecting null value on filed `favorite languages`

Comment: yes the "InsertPost.add(...)"is already surrounded by try-catch block I just didn't print it here in order to only show the code.
and in my table I haven't indicated the constraint NOT NULL

Comment: Awesome, I think you've read the guidelines for posting a question thoroughly, highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

//One suggestion: treat null and replace with empty String

```
 String name = (request.getParameter("name") == null ? "": request.getParameter("name"));
 String age = (request.getParameter("age") == null) ? "" : request.getParameter("age"));
 String[] lang = (request.getParameterValues("fav") == null) ? "": request.getParameterValues("fav"));
```

I hope it help you.